# Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.:141'

Tags: java, spring

I am getting this error ,  Exception thrown by application class

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.:141 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'luhnFormBean' available as request attribute

at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
at com.ibm._jsp._luhnCheck._jspx_meth_form_label_0(_luhnCheck.java:129)
at com.ibm._jsp._luhnCheck._jspx_meth_form_form_0(_luhnCheck.java:217)
at com.ibm._jsp._luhnCheck._jspService(_luhnCheck.java:98)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
at [internal classes]
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:215)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1033)
at [internal classes]
```

Please help

The code is placed below :

```
@Controller

public class LuhnController {


private ILuhnCheckService luhnCheckService;

public void setLuhnCheckService(ILuhnCheckService luhnCheckService){
this.luhnCheckService = luhnCheckService;
}

@ModelAttribute("luhnFormBean")
@RequestMapping(value = "/validateLuhn",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateLuhn(@ModelAttribute("luhnFormBean") LuhnFormBean luhnFormBean,Model model){
//  LuhnFormBean luhnFormBean= new LuhnFormBean();;
    System.out.println(luhnCheckService.validateLuhn(luhnFormBean.getCcNumber()));
     return "luhnFormBean";
}

@ModelAttribute("luhnFormBean")
@RequestMapping(value = "/validateLuhn",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView validateLuhn() {
    return new ModelAndView("/luhnCheck", "luhnFormBean", new LuhnFormBean());
 }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>example</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Example-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/jsp/home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

Example-Servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="example" />
      <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>



</beans>
```

JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Luhn Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <form:form method="" action="validate" modelAttribute="luhnFormBean">
            <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                <td><form:label path="ccNumber"><b> Card Number</b></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="ccNumber" /></td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few things wrong with your Spring controller.

First, you have `@ModelAttribute` specified at the method level. At the method level, the intent of the annotation is to share construction logic of the form bean for all `@RequestMapping` methods in the controller. The correct return type of methods annotated like is the form type, `LuhnFormBean`. Not the case here.

Second, the return type of a `@RequestMapping` bean is the view name (`String`) or the model and view (`ModelAndView`). Why does the `validateLuhn` method return the String `"luhnFormBean"`? Do you have such a view?

Third, for the same(!) method `validateLuhn`, you have `@ModelAttribute` defined at the method level and at the parameter level. The annotation for the parameter is to specify the form bean that will be bound to the form parameters, and the annotation for the method is to tell Spring how to create form bean. The same method cannot do both. That doesn't make sense!

Comment: @sh0rug0ru- Thank you for the answer, but i have corrected all the above said, still i am facing the same error, why at all we get this error

Comment: Reflect your changes in the question.

Comment: Also your form has a blank method (you do mean to POST, right?). The action specified is "validate", but the controller you specified doesn't map to that path.